# Using evaluate to perform claculation including an array

Tags: arrays, vba, string

I am trying to write a sub that can evaluate an equation which is a string and contains array elements. I tried it using evalaute, but it does not work.

```
Sub string_function()
Dim strg As String
Dim result As Variant
Dim vec() As Variant

ReDim vec(1 To 3)

vec(1) = 1
vec(2) = 3
vec(3) = 4

strg = "vec(1)+vec(2)+vec(3)"

result = Application.Evaluate(strg)

Debug.Print (result)
End Sub
```

Does anybody knwo how this could work? I only recieve. error 2029 :(

Comment: Evaluate is for worksheet formulas, not for VBA.  There is no facility in VBA for evaluating random strings containing VBA (unlike some other languages like js for example).

Comment: But the funny part is that this statement: `?Evaluate(vec(1) + vec(2) + vec(3))` works in Immediate window and results with `8`. Whereas in the Locals window it results with `Error 2029`.

Comment: @TomaszPaluch what?! That is really funny.

Comment: @TimWilliams okay that is a pity, so i have to come up with a different solution, but thank you